# Is it necessary to use constraints FOR ALL FOUR sides of a view in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Sometimes if you use 3 constraints the view is placed perfectly. So, is it a good practice to use constraints for all four sides of a view.

Comment: I think that is absolutely fine. It's probably also needed often enough for the views in the middle of a multi view layout...

Answer (score 2):

It's only necessary to set explicit constraints when they can't be determined by the values in `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

For example, if a view's `layout_width` is set to `match_parent`, the view's start/end constraints are implicitly the parent's start/end.

If the `layout_width` or `layout_height` of a view is set to `wrap_content`, you will have to define at least one horizontal or vertical constraint, as needed.

---

In the following example, only one constraint has to be defined:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Defining a bottom constraint instead would also be sufficient -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".  Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout